# Of course, I will

Tags: grammar

I want to know the answer of this question:    Most jobs (are getting-has get-get-got)less interesting as time goes by.

Answer (score 1):

> Most jobs are getting less interesting as time goes by.

Or

> Most jobs get less interesting as time goes by.

Are **both** correct!

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

The first statement uses the present tense and only refers to jobs now. It leaves open the possibility that most jobs used to get more interesting as time went by, or that they will do so in future.

The second statement is a general and universal opinion expressed in the present that relates to most jobs now, past and future. It excludes the possibility that most jobs ever got more interesting as time passed, or that they ever will ever do so.